# Dialog for mobile app fails to come out

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I'm developing an app by Jquery, and signup/login page occurs some problems with the signup/login dialogue. it doesn't come out when I click the trigger button, when I clicked the button, there is just nothing happens.

My home page looks like this:

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<title>Home Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "css/normalise.css" type="text/css" charset = "utf-8" src = "cordova-2.3.0.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" type="text/css" charset = "utf-8" src = "cordova-2.3.0.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.css" type="text/css" charset = "utf-8" src = "cordova-2.3.0.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.5.css" type="text/css" charset = "utf-8" src = "cordova-2.3.0.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "css/signup.css" type="text/css" charset = "utf-8" src = "cordova-2.3.0.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css"> <!-- Gem style -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->

</head>
<title>Welcome</title>

<body>

<img alt="full screen background image" src="images/background1.png" id="full-screen-background-image" /> 
<div class="intro__content">
            <div class="grid">
                <figure class="effect-bubba">

                    <img src="images/signup.png" alt="img02"/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>SIGN <span>UP</span></h2>

                        <a href="#cd-signup" class="ui-shadow cd-signup" data-transition="fade">View more</a>                       
                    </figcaption>   
                </a>                        
                </figure>
                <figure class="effect-bubba">
                    <img src="images/signin.png" alt="img16"/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>SIGN <span>IN</span></h2>

                        <a href="#cd-login" class="ui-shadow cd-signin"  >View more</a>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>
            </div>
</div>

<div class="cd-user-modal"> <!-- this is the entire modal form, including the background -->
    <div class="cd-user-modal-container"> <!-- this is the container wrapper -->
        <ul class="cd-switcher">
            <li><a href="#cd-login">Sign in</a></li>
            <li><a href="#cd-signup">New account</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="cd-login"> <!-- log in form -->
            <form class="cd-form">
                <p class="fieldset">
                    <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
                    <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signin-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                    <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signin-password">Password</label>
                    <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signin-password" type="text"  placeholder="Password">
                    <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Hide</a>
                    <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" checked>
                    <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <input class="full-width" type="submit" value="Login">
                </p>
            </form>

            <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Forgot your password?</a></p>
            <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
        </div> <!-- cd-login -->

        <div id="cd-signup"> <!-- sign up form -->
            <form class="cd-form">
                <p class="fieldset">
                    <label class="image-replace cd-username" for="signup-username">Username</label>
                    <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                    <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signup-email">E-mail</label>
                    <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                    <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signup-password">Password</label>
                    <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-password" type="text"  placeholder="Password">
                    <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Hide</a>
                    <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="accept-terms">
                    <label for="accept-terms">I agree to the <a href="#0">Terms</a></label>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit" value="Create account">
                </p>
            </form>

            <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
        </div> <!-- cd-signup -->

        <div id="cd-reset-password"> <!-- reset password form -->
            <p class="cd-form-message">Lost your password? Please enter your email address. You will receive a link to create a new password.</p>

            <form class="cd-form">
                <p class="fieldset">
                    <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="reset-email">E-mail</label>
                    <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="reset-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                    <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit" value="Reset password">
                </p>
            </form>

            <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Back to log-in</a></p>
        </div> <!-- cd-reset-password -->
        <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a>
    </div> <!-- cd-user-modal-container -->
```

```
<div id="carbonads-container">
    <div class="carbonad"><div id="azcarbon"></div><script type="text/javascript">var z = document.createElement("script"); z.type = "text/javascript"; z.async = true; z.src = "http://engine.carbonads.com/z/57881/azcarbon_2_1_0_HORIZ"; var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(z, s);</script>
    </div>
    <a href="#0" class="close-carbon-adv">Close</a>
</div> <!-- carbonads-container -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script> <!-- Gem jQuery -->  
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-48014931-1', 'codyhouse.co');
ga('send', 'pageview');

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.close-carbon-adv').on('click', function(){
        $('#carbonads-container').hide();
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>`
```